# Нестатическая инициализация статической переменной в java

Tags: java

Есть у меня вот такие поля и их инициализация

```
private String type;
private String name;
private static String aboba;
private static String description;
private static int animalCounter;

{
    aboba = "Abobus";
    description = "This is animal";
    animalCounter = 0;
    type = "No type";
    name = "No name";
}
```

Насколько корректно инициализировать таким образом статические поля?
Меняется ли работа программы, если не инициализировать статические поля статически?

Comment: Да, меняется. Например если ещё не создано ни одного экземпляра класса, то статика не проинициализируется.

Comment: и здесь ABOBA... когда гусенички пойдут в ход?)))